# Alaskan cruise visa requirements

Tags: canadian-citizens, us-visa, alaska

My daughter and I are Canadian citizens, taking an Alaskan cruise August 2022 and are wondering if we require US visas?

Answer (score 4):

**Canadian citizens do not need a visa to visit the US.**

Unless your cruise is a very strange you will not need a visa.